# Save generated SVG with svg.js as .svg file

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg.js

I'm trying to save the elements i'm creating with svg.js as a .svg file automatically after they are created. The library has the [svg()](https://svgjs.com/docs/3.0/importing-exporting/#import-export-svg) method to export SVG but I haven't found examples to learn how to use it. For example, if I want to save the rect I create in the code below, how could I do it?

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>SVG.js</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@svgdotjs/svg.js@3.0/dist/svg.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
var draw = SVG().addTo('body').size(300, 300);
var rect = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({ fill: '#f06' });
```

Comment: What do you mean with "saving shapes as SVG files"? Because that's not a thing. You can save SVG _documents_ as SVG file, but individual shapes are not a thing, you could save their `outerHTML` code as snippet, but then it's not an SVG file: it would most certainly fail SVG validation because it's missing the parts that need to go around it.

Comment: My bad. I meant SVG elements inside the SVG document. For example the rect element or the whole document as well.

Comment: Then it sounds like you're asking https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/issues/131, and I can strongly recommend searching the issue trackers of open source you use, because that's generally the first place to ask (SO is your last resort).

Comment: I took a look on that but the [svg.export.js](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.export.js) description says: _As of version 2 of SVG.js, this functionality is included in the main library. Therefore this plugin is obsolete if you are using version 2 and up._ I'm gonna try and use it anyway.

Comment: This is why I'm asking, because I didn't find information in the svg.js repo/docs nor the issue trackers.

Comment: Right, so the most important thing to do here is to _ask there_, so that _they_ can amend the documentation with that information. That way, the answer doesn't just benefit you, now, or SO users, now and later, but every single user of svg.js because they can just directly look up the information in the docs, where it should be. So please, make sure to do that, even if you keep this question open.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the right thing to do is ask on stackoverflow when there is a **question**. The issue tracker on github is exactly that - an _issue_ tracker. Only create an issue if you found something wrong with the code or the docs

Comment: @Fuzzyma If you need something from a project that for all intents and purposes should be doable, like saving an SVG document using something called svg.js, and the docs don't tell you how, then _that is an issue you should file_ because the docs need ammending. I've been in Open Source for 20+ years, maintainers want to know when their docs are insufficient: file it. No user should have to hit up Stackoverflow for what the docs can, and should, cover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On http://svgjs.dev there is a searchbar where you can just search for `export` and you will [find what you are looking for](https://svgjs.dev/docs/3.0/importing-exporting/#svg-as-getter):

> Exporting the full generated SVG, or a part of it, can be done with the svg() method:

```js
draw.svg()
```

> Exporting works on individual elements as well:

```js
var rect = draw.rect()
var svg  = rect.svg()
```

Now you have generated a string containing your svg. To download this string as a file (creating a file), a quick google search gives you a nice [solution](https://gist.github.com/danallison/3ec9d5314788b337b682):

```js
function downloadString(text, fileType, fileName) {
  var blob = new Blob([text], { type: fileType });

  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.download = fileName;
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  a.dataset.downloadurl = [fileType, a.download, a.href].join(':');
  a.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  document.body.removeChild(a);
  setTimeout(function() { URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href); }, 1500);
}

// downloadString("a,b,c\n1,2,3", "text/csv", "myCSV.csv")
```